# Вперемежку/вперемешку

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Я, гуляя в нашем осенне-зимнем лесу, видел там-сям хвоистые ивы, плачущие с утра до вечера, вперемежку/вперемешку с пихтами.`

Comment: История жизни. Он считал себя поэтом и очень хотел увидеть хотя бы в природе  предмет для своего вдохновения.   Увы! Высокой страсти не имея Для звуков жизни не щадить, Не мог он ямба от хорея, Как мы ни бились, отличить...

Comment: хвоистые ивы - это шедевр.

Comment: Художник так видит)) ХВОЯ, -и; ж. 1. Игловидные листья некоторых растений (сосны, ели, пихты, лиственницы и т.п.). Это ива с игловидными (узкими) листьями.  Сложный образ...

Comment: мне кажется, художнику рисующему хвоистые ивы стоит сходить к офтальмологу. это как развесистая клюква, только ива. Еще доставляет период гуляния, осенне-зимний, видимо, хвоистые ивы были в самом цвету плодоношения.

Comment: Я кстати понял, что меня раздражает: я  воспринимаю слова и язык, как к способ отражения мира. А тут, это не слова и не язык, это абстрактное пространство нереферентных объектов - это не речь и не математика даже. Абстракция на абстракции сидит и абстракцией погоняет. Даже у чепухи есть свои пределы.

Comment: Это же не реальные, а обобщенные образы. Другими словами, русский символизм, продолжение традиций. В точности как здесь:  "Помимо поисков новых литературных перспектив в форме и тематике, возможно, единственное, что объединяло русских символистов — это НЕДОВЕРИЕ к обыденному слову, стремление выражаться посредством аллегорий и символов".

Comment: не вижу символизма и аллегорий, вижу непонятно что ради запятой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я, гуляя в нашем осенне-зимнем лесу, видел там-сям хвоистые ивы, плачущие с утра до вечера, **вперемешку** с пихтами.*

***Вперемешку*** — слова "мешать", а ***вперемежку*** — от слова "межа". В данном случае это был смешанный лес (потому что *там-сям*).

**Примечание**

В то же время можно посадить деревья рядами: ивы ***вперемежку*** с пихтами.  Можно  также представить такой лес...

Comment: Не сочтите за критику – просто для справки…
Из сборника диктантов по русскому для 5—7 классов:


_Противоположный берег плеса был обрывист, крут, по верху его вплотную к самому обрыву подступал старый **смешанный** лес: дубы и вязы **вперемежку** с дикими яблонями, вербы, тополя и осины_…  [По М. Шолохову]

Comment: А что не так?  Полоса дубов и вязов,  потом рядочек яблонь и т.д.